# Vue Nested Route router-view not working if parent router-view is rendered in a slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a ContainerMain component in which the RouterView is rendered as a simple default slot in a MainLayout Component.

```
// routes.ts
const mainMenuRoutes = [{
    path: "blood-drop",
    name: RouteNameMenu.MENU_BLOOD_DROP,
    component: BloodDropMain,
    children: [
      {
        path: "checkups",
        name: RouteName.BLOOD_CHECKUPS,
        component: CheckupResults,
      }
    ],
}];

{
    path: "/",
    name: RouteName.MENU_MAIN,
    component: ContainerMain,
    children: mainMenuRoutes,
 }
```

```
// ContainerMain.vue

<template>
  <!-- <RouterView /> --> THIS WILL WORK !!!

  <MainLayout>    ---> THIS DOESN'T WORK !!!
    <RouterView />
  </MainLayout>
  <div></div>
</template>
```

If I navigate to '/blood-drop' I get the BloodDrop Component rendered successfully. But when I navigate or refresh to '/blood-drop/checkups' I get an error.

```
// BloodDropMain.vue

<template>
  <div class="blood-drop-container">
    ...etc
    <div class="content">
      <RouterView />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvS7Y.png)

If however I move out the parent <RouterView /> outside of <MainLayout></MainLayout> it will work, no error, except of course not having the correct UI.

Comment: Component hierarchy should match routes hierarchy. I.e. if your top route is `blood-drop` - then `ContainerMain` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think this is what is happening here, `blood-drop` route is a child of for `/` route which renders the ContainerMain. I have many routes in the `mainMenuRoutes` array and everything works fine, the problem appears when I have children in those routes